# xcodebuild fails with error=nsconsumed-mismatch when using Xcode11 iOS13 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ios13

I use the following command to build/archive my project:

```
xcodebuild -UseNewBuildSystem=NO -workspace WORKSPACE -scheme TARGET clean archive
```

The compilation fails with the following error:

```
error: -Werror=nsconsumed-mismatch is currently enabled, but was not in the PCH file
```

The same build command works when building against Xcode 10.2/10.3 and iOS 12 sdk.